# Facebook Login button in HelloFacebookSample in ios not showing

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am new in IOS app dev. 
I tried migrating HelloFacebookSample code into my project. I have carefully copied, checked and compared both codes. But the blue facebook login button is not showing once I run my project.

I have added the FacebookSDKResources.bundle as advised in the tutorials but still there is no blue login button.

Please help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have just added it graphically as instructed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0